# Access a value inside ICollection

Tags: .net, collections, bots, icollection

```
string greeting = "";    
foreach (System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<object> x in greetingRecommendation.Resolution.Values)
    {
           foreach (var y in x)
           {
               greeting = (string)y;
           }
    }
```

I need to retrieve the "Good Morning" value which is inside "greetingRecommendation.Resolution.Values" I did it as above(using a foreach) and its working. But is there a better way to access that single value.
[image]

Comment: Did you try searching an answer to your question before posting? Your question is trivial.

Comment: I did some google and I found that ICollection has the ElementAt method. If you know the index of the value that you want to access then you can invoke the ElementAt method and this suppose to return the value much more quickly then using foreach loop . Note that it is an extension method.

Comment: I tried to use ElementAt. but there's no method available

Comment: Because it is extension. I found it here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx under the list of extension methods. However you can invoke the CopyTo method to copy 1 value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ for querying a collection in a simpler way.

Let's take as an example the following collection:

```
var objCollection = (ICollection<object>) new List<object>
{
    "Good Morning",
    "Good Afternoon",
    "Good Night"
};
```

Now we can extract the first, last or an item at a specific index with the following:

```
var firstItem = objCollection.First(); // returns "Good Morning"
var lastItem = objCollection.Last(); // returns "Good Night"
var itemAtIndex1 = objCollection.ElementAt(1); // returns "Good Afternoon"
```

There is also `OrDefault` variants of all the previous. The difference is that `First` will throw an exception if `objCollection` has no items, but `FirstOrDefault` will simply return `default(object)` (which is `null` by the way) if `objCollection` has no items.

For putting an example, this is how `OrDefault` variants can be used:

```
var firstItem = objCollection.FirstOrDefault(); // returns "Good Morning"
var lastItem = objCollection.LastOrDefault(); // returns "Good Night"
var itemAtIndex99 = objCollection.ElementAtOrDefault(99); // returns null, because `objCollection` has only three items and the index 99 doesn't exist on it
```

In the scenario of `greetingRecommendation.Resolution.Values`, something like the following can be used for retrieving the first item of the collection:

`var greeting = greetingRecommendation.Resolution.Values.FirstOrDefault() as string;`

Let's assume that `Values` property is of type `ICollection<object>`.

That line will ensure that:

- If `Values` property has no items, no exception will be thrown, and `default(object)` would be returned.
- The first item in `Values` property will be safely casted to a `string`, to avoid issues if it contains a value that can not be casted to `string`. If the value can not be casted, `default(string)` (which is `null`) will be returned.
- The variable `greeting` will contain either `null` or a `string` with the first value of the `Values` property.

Do not forget to add a `using System.Linq;` in the using directives to be able to use LINQ.

I've prepared a .NET Fiddle in the following link for seeing such LINQ operations in action:

- [Fiddle for LINQ on Collections](https://dotnetfiddle.net/USaUEC)